# Will I have a smaller time complexity if I use both the head and tail pointers in a doubly linked list to search an element?

Tags: search, time-complexity, doubly-linked-list

So if I want to search an element,using a doubly-linked list,will I get a less consuming time complexity such as O(logN) if I search from both sides(the beginning of the list and the end of the list) at the same time or will I still get linear time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still get linear time complexity if you're traversing links in a doubly-linked list. Binary search's logarithmic time complexity depends on index-based random access of array elements in a sorted list. Consider a doubly-linked list with n/2 instances of a constant c followed by n/2 instances of  2c. To determine a number b where c < b < 2c is not in such a list you'd definitely have to check n/2 entries regardless of which end you search from. Even having the entries in sorted order doesn't help since to check the middle you'd need to traverse half the list.